# What is the issue with our links? It creates a loop

Tags: permalinks, links, homepage

On behalf of the university's radio station, I am trying to solve the issue with our links.

When you go to our site http://brookesradio.com, if you click one of the nav bar or header, twice or go to the front page the link becomes 'http://brookesradio.com/#http://brookesradio.com/' and then if it is a category or page the page title.

What is causing this issue, I tried a few things like manual links and looking through the theme's setting but nothing was jumping out at me.

Thanks for reading
Mike.

Comment: Most likely something in you theme is doing this but it could be a poorly written plugin. If you can narrow things down you stand a better chance of getting a good answer. Personally, I suspect you have relative links somewhere but I don't have time to dig around your site right now.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to code in your script.js. I'm guessing it is somehow a 'feature' of your theme.

The URL after the hash allows the site to load the new page via ajax, into your home page. So effectively, the user never leaves the home page. I'm not sure what this would do to your stats (if you use them).

I can't see offhand where in the code the hash is actually being added to your links. Although the site basically works without this hash/ajax system, some JS errors are thrown if you don't use it.

Comment: Excellent. I'll have to ask for further permissions now, either that or we get a new theme.

Comment: It would be worth having a look at the JS to see if it is. But a new theme is plausible because of the fact we have gone from orange to being blue.

Comment: Actually I meant: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green". I wasn't being philosophical :)

Comment: Oh right, well I'll see what other people will post first.

Comment: I have elaborated slightly in my otherwise vague answer.

Comment: Ah thanks, what would you recommend the cause of action be?

Comment: The course of action? The Ajax thing seems to be integral to your current theme (which I think is custom-built?). If you don't like the hash/ajax effect (and I don't), and you are due a theme update, I would do just that. The Ajax loading is a completely unnecessary complication.